# Let $f(x^4+8x)=24x$ where $x < 0$, find $f^\prime(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> Let $f(x^4+8x)=24x$ where $x < 0$,
> which of the following equals to  $f^\prime(0)$ ?
>
> $\text{a)}~1~~~~\text{b)}~-1~~~~\text{c)}~2~~~~\text{d)}~ -2$

This question was asked in high school science competition. The official solution is $\text{a)}$ but I don't know how to solve it.

#### My solution

From my observation, $f(x)$ takes a function and output $3^{rd}$ drivative of it. So,
$$f(x) = \frac{d^3x}{dt^3}$$

Therefore, for a constant function $c$. $f(c) = 0$. which imply

$$ f^\prime(0) = 0 $$

which is not correct. I couldn't find where the error is. so a help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the domain of $f$ ? Is it $\Bbb R^-$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f'(x^4+8x)(4x^3+8)=24,$$ which for $x=-2$ gives
$$(-24)f'(0)=24$$ or $$f'(0)=-1.$$

Comment: What's the meaning of $x<0$ in the question ?

Comment: I think the OP stated that the answer was $a) 1$. Does this mean that the official answer is wrong?

Comment: BTW is it $f'[(x^4+8x)(4x^3+8)]=24$?

Comment: @Mohammad Zuhair Khan  I wrote $f'(x^4+8x)(4x^3+8)=24.$ I think your writing is wrong.

Comment: Could $x=^3\sqrt {-2}$ work too?

Comment: @Mohammad Zuhair Khan  No. What do you think?

Comment: @Empty $x^4+8x=0$ for $x=0$ or $x=-2$ and since $x<0$, we can assume $x=-2$.

Comment: Oh I had assumed that it was $f'[(x^4+8x)(4x^3+8)]=24$. Then $x=^3\sqrt {-2}$ would also give a solution. My apologies.

Comment: @Mohammad Zuhair $\sqrt[3]{-2}\neq\sqrt[3]{-8}.$

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating it with respect to $x$, putting $0$ or $-2$ can make the argument of $f'(x^4+8x)$ equal to $0$, but since the equation is valid only for $x<0$, put $x=-2$ and answer comes out to be $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$f′(x^4+8x)(4x^3+8)=24 $,
 now u want $f'(0)$ for $x<0$.
 So put $x^4+8x=0$,
 which gives $x=0,-2$,
$x=0$ is rejected since $x<0$.
 So, $x=-2$.
 Put $x=-2$ in $$f′(x^4+8x)(4x^3+8)=24$$
You will get $f'(0)\times(-24)=24$,
or, $f'(0)=-1$.
 You get option $\text{b}$ instead of $\text{a}$.